# DataSet.Fill slower after upgrading to oracle 11g

Tags: web-server, .net, oracle-11g, oracle10g

We have migrated from an oracle 10g to an oracle 11g Database.

The instance of Database 11g is totally new an installed on a VirtualMachine in a different HW. The new DB is on Windows Server 2013 while the old one is on Windows Server 2008 sp2.

We have imported the old 10g database to the new 11g database.

The overall performance of the new DB is much faster than the old on sqlplus but not when queried through web services.

The WebService is the same. Calling the same qry the DataSet.Fill on the old DB is 3 time faster than the new DB.

Calling the same query with sqlplus on the PC hosting the web server, the query is fast on both sides and faster on the new side.

So I think that the problem could be in the listener configuration but I haven't a clue where to start configuring it in order to increase the websevice performances...

Any idea?

Comment: It seems that only functions returning SYS_REFCURSOR are affected by an overhead of 0.5 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the execution plan, that I've found different in the imported DB.

Comment: It would be nice if you could extend this answer with just a little bit more detail.

Comment: It's been difficult to find the problem because the performance issue was visible only calling the function with .net and not with sqlplus. After many trials I found that regenerating the indexes brought the same performance in each db instance.